# postgresql polygon location query

Tags: postgresql, cartodb

Can someone help me writing a query to find all nearest polygons to a 
latitude-longitude.

So ill provide the lat/long and i want to find all nearest polygons.

This is what i have so far:

```
SELECT name
FROM questions_radius
WHERE mdsys.sdo_within_distance(
the_geom, 
mdsys.sdo_geometry(2001, 8307, mdsys.sdo_point_type( 
-120, 43, null), null, null), 'distance=500 unit=FOOT')= 'TRUE'
```

but that gives me an error:
schema "mdsys" does not exist. Im using cartoDB. anyone know how to perform this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself =)

Heres what I used:

```
SELECT * FROM questions_radius 
WHERE ST_DWithin(the_geom::geography,
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint([user_latitude], [user_longitude]), 4326)::geography, [distance_in_meters])
ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint([user_latitude],[user_longitude]),4326) ASC
LIMIT 100
```

This works to query both points and polygons closest to a users location. Just provide the latitude, longitude and distance in meters to perform the query and your done. It´s pretty fast. Hope this helps anyone looking to perform some cool geospatial queries. =)